# How do I connect to two different Cassandra clusters from a Spring WebFlux application?

Tags: cassandra, spring-webflux

I need to connect to two different Cassandra clusters from my app. Do you have an example of how I could do this in Spring WebFlux?

I've tried to look for examples on the web but I couldn't find one that was clear enough to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define two Cassandra sessions using the `@Bean` annotation, each with its own set of contact points and CQL client port. The example below shows variables created with the `@Value` annotation to retrieve the configuration parameters from the `application.properties` file.

```
@Configuration
public class CassandraConfiguration {

    @Value("${cassandra1.contactPoints}")
    private String cassandra1ContactPoints;

    @Value("${cassandra2.contactPoints}")
    private String cassandra2ContactPoints;

    @Value("${cassandra1.port}")
    private int cassandra1Port;

    @Value("${cassandra2.port}")
    private int cassandra2Port;

    @Value("${cassandra1.keyspace}")
    private String cassandra1Keyspace;

    @Value("${cassandra2.keyspace}")
    private String cassandra2Keyspace;

    @Bean("cassandra1Session")
    public CqlSession cassandra1Session() {
        CqlSession session = Cluster.builder()
            .addContactPoints(cassandra1ContactPoints.split(","))
            .withPort(cassandra1Port)
            .build();
        return session.connect(cassandra1Keyspace);
    }

    @Bean("cassandra2Session")
    public CqlSession cassandra2Session() {
        CqlSession session = Cluster.builder()
            .addContactPoints(cassandra2ContactPoints.split(","))
            .withPort(cassandra2Port)
            .build();
        return session.connect(cassandra2Keyspace);
    }
}
```

These sessions `cassandra1Session` and `cassandra1Session` can then be used in the WebFlux controller. For example:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("cassandra1Session")
    private CqlSession cassandra1Session;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("cassandra2Session")
    private CqlSession cassandra2Session;

    @GetMapping("/cassandra1Data")
    public Flux<Row> getCassandra1Data() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
        return cassandra1Session.executeReactive(query).flux();
    }

    @GetMapping("/cassandra2Data")
    public Flux<Row> getCassandra2Data() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
        return cassandra2Session.executeReactive(query).flux();
    }
}
```

Note that the `@Autowired` annotation is used to inject the Cassandra sessions into the controller, with the `@Qualifier` annotation used to specify the session to inject. Cheers!